# Why is the variable value not moving into the register?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I am embarking on the journey of learning assembly language. I am using emu8086 to practice. I have run into a small problem that I can't seem to figure out though--likely due to lack of knowledge in assembly. I just want to move the value of the variable named 'loopCount' to the register cx. When I run the emulator I can see the value of the variable is assigned correctly but when the code gets to the mov statement, it appears to assign what I think is the address to the register cx. What I want to accomplish is assign the value of the variable (5) to the register cx.

Here is the code I'm trying to run:

```
data segment
    loopCount dw 5;
ends

stack segment
    dw   128  dup(0)
ends

code segment

start:
    mov cx,loopCount;

    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h  
ends
end start
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the **contents** of the location `loopcount`, not the **value** of `loopcount`.

```
mov cx,[loopcount]
```

or

```
mov cx,word ptr loopcount
```

should accomplish this, depending on your assembler [settings].

---

Hmm - Seems to need to have DS manually pointed to data segment...

```
mov cx,@data
mov ds,cx
mov cx,[loopCount];
```

Comment: I tried both. Still getting what seems to be the address going to register cx.

Comment: The code works now. I'll have to do some digging to learn how @data and mov ds,cx works. Thanks!